# what does the brackets after function name do when calling a function in scala?

Tags: scala

When reading some scala code, i see something like fooString
but I couldn't find anything that expalins this sort of commands when calling a function.

I know we should define the parameter and expected return type in scala when defining a function or class. Consider this code:

```
def socketTextStream(
    hostname: String,port: Int
   ): ReceiverInputDStream[String] = withNamedScope("socket text stream") {
  socketStream[String](hostname, port, SocketReceiver.bytesToLines)
}
```

what [String] after "socketStream" do here and I wonder why there is another function( withNamedScope) after "=" here.

Comment: It’s scala’s generics syntax.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble didn't find anything like this in any tutorial. I mean when calling a function

Comment: `[String]` is generics, like `List[Int]`. The method after equals is just the body of socketTextStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `def socketTextStream(hostname: String, port: Int): ReceiverInputDStream[String]` is declaring a method called **socketTextStream** which receives two inputs *(**host** & **port**)* and returns a **ReceiverInputDStream** which is a [generic class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html), and in this case the result will be parameterized with the type **String**.

Then, `= withNamedScope("socket text stream") { .. }` means that the implementation of that method is call other method *(**withNamedScope**)* that takes a **String** *(presumably a name)* as its first argument, and a block *(probably a [by name parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html))* as its second argument.
In this case, the two arguments are on separated parameters lists, which is called [currying](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/currying.html).

Finally, `socketStream[String](hostname, port, SocketReceiver.bytesToLines)` *(which is the body of the block)* is calling another method **socketStream** which is a [polymorphic / generic method](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html).
The `[String]` part is specifying that the type parameter of that method, is **String**. Maybe this information is redundant or maybe it is used to force an specific implicit, without the definition of such method is hard to tell.

---

Anyways, all here is basic syntax and structures of the language, all covered by the tour *(which many people highlight for being too brief and just covering the basis of the language)*. Thus, I would recommend you to check more resources before continue with reading code.